# python3 pdb: how to repeat multiple commands

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

How do you repeat a multiple commands?

```
Multiple commands may be entered on a single line, separated by ;;.
[...]
Entering a blank line repeats the last command entered.
```

I have already tried:

```
n ;; l
<ENTER>
```

But only the list command would be repeated.

Sticking with pdb (no ipdb & co), would you know how to repeat effortlessly multiple commands?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @Song, the reason you can't repeat the desired behavior, i.e. stepping rather than showing context, is because the last command in `n ;; l` is `l`.

The way I get around this is to use caps for my aliases.  Here is what my `.pdbrc` file looks like:

```
# Enable completion
import pdb
import rlcompleter
pdb.Pdb.complete=rlcompleter.Completer(locals()).complete

# Show context on startup
l

alias S 'Stepping into...' ;; step ;; l
alias N 'Stepping over...' ;; next ;; l
alias C 'Continuing...' ;; continue ;; l
alias R 'Going to return...' ;; return ;; l
```

The preceding strings `"Stepping into..."`, etc. let you know when you're executing a custom command versus a native `pdb` command.

These same commands work for `ipdb`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the documentation [https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html](http://documentation) says

> Exception: if the last command was a list command, the next 11 lines
>   are listed.

just right after

> Entering a blank line repeats the last command entered

you've mentioned

In your expression

> n;;l

as we can see the list command 'l' appears to be the last given command which directly hits the exception

I've faced the same problem and found some sort of a solution - we can simply repeat the last command `n;;l` by pressing up-arrow key and then enter, just like in terminal. Hope this helps.